# Wrong Prediction on Dumping the ML model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying to train a mlp model, data points are transformed to hashes and then passed to model...
While training i am using the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

def hashing_trick(open_ports, n_features=1000):
    hashed_features = np.zeros(n_features)
    for port in open_ports:
        hash_value = hash(port) % n_features
        hashed_features[hash_value] = 1
    return hashed_features

output_file_path = "shodan_fetched_data.json"
with open(output_file_path, "r") as output_file:
    data =json.load(output_file)
# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.drop("index",axis =1,inplace = True)


df['hashed_open_ports'] = df['open_ports'].apply(lambda x: hashing_trick(x))
hashed_features = np.array(df['hashed_open_ports'].to_list())
dbscan = DBSCAN(eps =0.4,min_samples=2)
clusters = dbscan.fit_predict(hashed_features)
df['port_cluster'] = clusters


X = np.vstack(df['hashed_open_ports'].values)
y = df['port_cluster']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size =0.2, random_state=42)


model = MLPClassifier(random_state=42)

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy:.2f}")
new_open_ports = hashing_trick(['22/ssh', '80/http', '443/https'])

new_entry = np.array([new_open_ports]).reshape(1, -1)
model.predict(new_entry)
model_filename = 'mlp_model.joblib'
joblib.dump(model, model_filename)
```

This gives accuracy of 93% with cluster as 0. which is correct.
But when i load the model and use that to predict it gives accuracy of 17 % with cluster as -1

```
import joblib
import numpy as np# Dump the trained model to a file
def hashing_trick(open_ports, n_features=1000):
    hashed_features = np.zeros(n_features)
    for port in open_ports:
        hash_value = hash(port) % n_features
        hashed_features[hash_value] = 1
    return hashed_features
model_filename = 'mlp_model.joblib'

# Load the saved model
loaded_model = joblib.load(model_filename)

# Predict using the loaded model
new_open_ports = hashing_trick(['22/ssh', '80/http', '443/https'])
new_entry = np.array([new_open_ports]).reshape(1, -1)
predicted_cluster = loaded_model.predict(new_entry)
print(f"Predicted Cluster: {predicted_cluster[0]}")
```

Why is it failing and how to correct it?

I trained many models on same hashing, but all gave same results on dumping. maybe the problem is in hashing trick function.

Comment: Can i ask you to show us an example of record of your dataset?

Comment: Have you tried loading the model and then predicting on the same test set which gave an accuracy of 93% ?

Comment: @MarcoParola Sorry for late reply...This is the subset of my df["open_ports"]:

0       [55790/http, 51036/http, 46272/http, 50144/rdp...
1                            [22/ssh, 80/http, 443/https]
2                                       [22/ssh, 80/http]
3                                                [22/ssh]
4                                               [80/http]
                              ...                        
6686                                            [80/http]
6687                                                   []

Comment: @rr_goyal... yes i tried, until i am not restarting my kernel , it gives 93 % accuracy, but once i restart the kernel and now test again on the same dataset , it gives accuracy of 6 %

Comment: Did you check if the model is correctly saved after the training?

Comment: @MarcoParola Yes I checked, Now after some experiments with my code, i get to know that the problem is somewhere in data processing , as model fails only when i re process the data for testing , maybe something to do with hashtrick function or dataframe,... I tried to dump the df with was created by reading the json file, that only dumping and loading is giving variations in process.....

Comment: Most of the resources I tried saved their model as "model_name.sav" or "model_name.pkl". Can you try using these extensions ?

Comment: @rr_goyal tried all extension....The problem is somewhere between hashing trick and saving it in df